# Migrating a herokuapp to EU and keeping the same name

Tags: django, heroku

I have an iOS app that has been submitted to app store, and for commercial reasons we don't want another version soon. This iOS app refers to the server at `myapp.herokuapp.com`

All the users of the iOS app would be in the UK, and hence it makes sense for me to move `myapp` which is current in Heroku US (and whose static storage is an AWS S3 bucket in US) to move to Heroku EU region (and get a corresponding AWS S3 bucket in the EU)

I did the following :

```
$ heroku fork -a myapp myappeu --region eu
```

However this means that my iOS code should be changed to refer to the server `myappeu.herokuapp.com` , which cannot be done until version 2 of the iOS app

Is there any other way of doing it, like deleteing `myapp` and renaming `myappeu` as `myapp`?

Comment: It doesn't help you now, but you should really register a proper domain. They're not expensive, and mean that you can move the host wherever you like without affecting anything.

Comment: Thanks for the input Daniel. To dig a bit further, I do have a myapp.co.uk domain, and it has a proper marketing website for our app. I want to use (in future) the BASE URL in the iOS app as myapp.co.uk/app/ . How do I achieve this? Does changing the DNS resolution settings help in this respect (meaning I am redirecting not full domain but a subdomain)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The heroku app namespace is global, so you'll need to free up your current app name first.  You are correct though that you could fork your app into the EU region, delete the old app and then rename your EU fork to the original app name.